# How to add a host route to OpenVPN server

Tags: openvpn

I have a service that is on an internet IP. When a client is connected to the VPN I need them to access that service using the VPN server and not through their local machines default route.

From what I can tell, I need to tell the openvpn server to push a route to the client. So, using something to the extent of this is:

```
push "route 50.1.2.3 255.255.255.255"
```

I tried placing this in my /usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/as.conf however it doesn't seem to pick it up.

this is how I verify:

```
1) updating the file
2) systemctl restart <service>
3) reconnecting the vpn client
4) Using netstat -rn (mac) to search for a route with IP 50.1.2.3
```

However I'm also confused about the format of my as.conf file on my vpnserver. All my google searches show me that openvpn .conf file should look like:

```
parameter_name parameter_value
```

my as.conf file is in the following format:

```
parameter_name=parameter_value
```

why is that?

this is my version of openvpn and OS:

```
openvpnas@openvpnas2:~$ more /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial

openvpnas@openvpnas2:/usr/local/openvpn_as/etc$ dpkg -l | grep openvpn
ii  openvpn-as                            2.1.9-Ubuntu16                        amd64        openvpn-as
```

Comment: There is no default config file, its location is given as argument to the `openvpn` executable. You can use `ps` to find them (the options depend on the OS on the server). As an example the `openvpn@as.service` on Debianoids reads its config from `/etc/openvpn/as.conf`.

Comment: Thanks @PiotrP.Karwasz. I've updated my post with more content.

Comment: You are not running an OpenVPN server, but an OpenVPN Access Server (cf. [documentation](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/how-to-configure-the-openvpn-access-server/)), which has a different configuration format (as you noticed). In the end it will probably generate a classical configuration file for OpenVPN.

Comment: Hi @PiotrP.Karwasz. Classical format as in - parameter_name parameter_value ? I was looking for that also. a conf file with a format of - parameter_name parameter_value. however I haven't found it yet, I'll take another gander though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for the answer.

From the console ui:

```
1) VPN Settings
2) Routing
3) Specify the private subnets to which all clients should be given access (as 'network/netmask_bits', one per line):
4) Enter: 50.1.2.3/32
```